# Unidirectional path tracer output is too dark

Tags: c++, rendering, raytracing

I am writing a CPU raytracer that runs on Windows. Unfortunately current outputs seems too dark, like i am missing global illumination.

Here is an interior room with lighting that comes from 2 windows. There is only one directional light. Number of light bounces is set to 8.

Here my path tracer output:

[image]

Blender Cycles output:

[image]

While direct lighting is good, it feels like i am missing global illumination. But why?

Here is the sample code:

```
RGBColor pathTracing(const Math::Ray& ray, nbUint32 depth)
{
    // Find intersection using intel's Embree
    Intersector::IntersectionInfo isectInfo;
    m_intersector->intersect(ray, isectInfo);

    // Check if an intersection occured
    if (isectInfo.object == nullptr)
    {
        return BlackRGBColor;
    }

    // Get intersection properties
    const auto isectProps = buildIntersectionProperties(ray, isectInfo, m_currentScene);

    // The scene model
    const auto& model = m_currentScene->getModel();

    // Read the material
    const DatabaseMaterialPtr material = model->getMaterialPtr_FromEntity(isectInfo.object->getMaterialId());

    // Compute direct lighning
    RGBColor directCont = BlackRGBColor;
    {
        for (const EntityIdentifier& lightId : m_currentScene->getLights())
        {
            // Generate light sample
            const auto light = Entity::EntityDatabaseSingleton::instance()->getEntity<Light::BaseLight>(lightId);
            const auto sampleToLight = light->generateSampleToLight(isectProps.P);

            const nbFloat32 NoL = glm::dot(isectProps.BsdfProps.N, sampleToLight.L);
            if (NoL <= 0.0f)
                continue;

            // Compute occlusion
            Math::Ray shadowRay(isectProps.deltaP, sampleToLight.L, sampleToLight.length);
            const nbFloat32 occlusionStrength = m_intersector->occlusion(shadowRay);

            if (occlusionStrength != 1.0f)
            {
                // Build the bsdf sample struture
                Material::BaseMaterial::SampleBsdfData bsdfSample;
                bsdfSample.L = sampleToLight.L;
                bsdfSample.V = isectProps.V;
                bsdfSample.NoL = NoL;
                bsdfSample.geoProps = &isectProps.BsdfProps;

                // Sample the brdf to get the scale
                auto sampledBrdf = material.sampleBsdf(bsdfSample);

                // Multiply by light radiance
                sampledBrdf *= light->getColor();

                // Multiply by visibility
                sampledBrdf *= (1.0f - occlusionStrength);

                // Finally add light contribution
                directCont += sampledBrdf;
            }
        }
    }


    // Compute indirect lighning
    RGBColor indirectCont;
    if (++depth <= m_settings.m_maxDepth)
    {
        BaseMaterial::SpawnRayResult newRayData;
        newRayData = material->spawnRay(/* some parameters*/);

        // Build the bsdf sample struture
        Material::BaseMaterial::SampleBsdfData bsdfSample;
        bsdfSample.L = newRayData.ray.getDirection();
        bsdfSample.V = isectProps.V;
        bsdfSample.NoL = glm::dot(newRayData.ray.getDirection(), isectProps.BsdfProps.N);
        bsdfSample.geoProps = &isectProps.BsdfProps;

        // Indirect raytracing
        const Spectrum sampledBrdf = material->sampleBsdf(bsdfSample);
        const Spectrum sampledRadiance = sampledBrdf * pathTracing(newRayData.ray, depth);//recursion

        static const float normalizationFactor = 2.0f * Math::Pi.getValue();
        indirectCont = sampledRadiance * normalizationFactor;
    }

    return directCont + indirectCont;
}
```

And here more code snippets.

The sampleBsdf method

```
RGBColor BaseMaterial::sampleBsdf(const SampleBsdfData& data) const
{
    DistributionFunction::SampleInput distSampleInput;
    distSampleInput.L = data.L;
    distSampleInput.V = data.V;
    distSampleInput.N = data.geoProps->N;
    distSampleInput.T = data.geoProps->T;
    distSampleInput.B = data.geoProps->B;
    distSampleInput.H = glm::normalize(data.L + data.V);

    distSampleInput.HoN = std::abs(glm::dot(data.geoProps->N, distSampleInput.H));
    distSampleInput.NoV = std::abs(glm::dot(data.geoProps->N, data.V));
    distSampleInput.NoL = data.NoL;


    return sampleBrdf(distSampleInput) * distSampleInput.NoL;
}
```

The sampleBrdf method

```
inline nbFloat32 lambert(const SampleInput& input)
{
    return Math::InvPi.getValue();
}

nbFloat32 blinnPhong(const SampleInput& input, nbFloat32 shininess)
{
    const nbFloat32 HoN = std::min(input.HoN, 0.999f);
    nbFloat32 normalizationFactor = (shininess + 8.0f) * Math::InvPi8.getValue();
    normalizationFactor = glm::clamp(normalizationFactor, 0.0f, 1.0f);

    return std::pow(HoN, shininess) * normalizationFactor;
}

#define NO_FRESNEL_VALUE 0.4f

nbFloat32 DefaultDielectric::sampleFresnel(nbFloat32 HoN) const
{
    if (m_fresnelEnabled)
    {
        // Schlick approximation.
        return glm::clamp(m_fresnel0 + (1.0f - m_fresnel0) * pow(1.0f - HoN, 5.0f), 0.0f, 1.0f);
    }

    return NO_FRESNEL_VALUE;
}

RGBColor DefaultDielectric::sampleBrdf(DistributionFunction::SampleInput& distSampleInput) const
{
    nbFloat32 fresnelFactor = sampleFresnel(distSampleInput.HoN);

    // Diffuse
    nbFloat32 diffuseFactor = lambert(distSampleInput) * (1.0f - fresnelFactor);
    auto diffuseLightning = m_diffuse * diffuseFactor;

    // Specular
    nbFloat32 specularFactor = blinnPhong(distSampleInput, m_glossiness) * fresnelFactor;
    auto specLightning = m_specular * specularFactor;

    return m_opacity * (diffuseLightning + specLightning);
}
```

Comment: Even the dark areas in your picture look like half grey. I'd troubleshoot that first - why aren't the darkest parts black? Even if your program is making the wrong things bright and dark there should still be dark things.

Comment: Thanks for helping. My raytracer scenes have an ambient term. But when i set it to zero it is total darkness:
https://imgur.com/a/vbp1Gg6

Comment: I expect a raytraced scene to have direct and bounced light and very little ambient. If you look at your first picture it looks like the ambient light is only serving to make the overall image brighter - as if you just added the same number to all the RGB values. The last picture shows the direct lighting from the sun is working. Question is why the bounced light is so dark.

Comment: I'm no expert on ray tracing. I guess you have already tried just making the BSDF have bigger numbers? That seems too obvious

Comment: I just tried. Adding a factor to the bsdf definitely make the scene brighter. I will post code from the missing part.

Comment: I don't even know what BSDF stands for, and I thought of that. So I'm really wondering why you didn't.

Comment: Also: I know the human eye has something like logarithmic brightness perception, whereas your code seems to be calculating things linearly i.e. you are trying to actually calculate the number of photons, not the perceived brightness. I don't know where this conversion usually fits into ray-tracing pipelines. I imagine they probably do the calculations logarithmically.

Comment: apparently there can be a factor of (roughly) 10 difference between the direct sunlight and the ambient light in a typical room. You wouldn't want the direct sunlight pixels to be 255,255,255 and everywhere else to be darker than 30,30,30.

Comment: Even without ambient light I should get consequent global illumination.

Comment: For the logarithmic stuff i think you are referring to the srgb space:
https://learnopengl.com/Advanced-Lighting/Gamma-Correction

Comment: oh, might be. Are you converting linear to sRGB?

Comment: I wasnt. Adding gamme correction seems to solve te issue:
https://imgur.com/a/2lhMRDQ
I will do some testing to be sure

Comment: Here we are. With a gamma of 2.2:
https://imgur.com/a/gmKl5rC

With an exagerated gamma of 4.0:
https://imgur.com/a/zbwd9U3

While gamma correction helps, it is still not the fix i think.

Comment: I still suspect the logarithmic brightness thing, though I don't really know what I'm talking about. Maybe you can try a tone mapping operator, the same sort used by HDR rendering: https://bruop.github.io/tonemapping/

Comment: How bright is the light? as I mentioned before, if the direct sunlight is 255,255,255 RGB, then the rest of the room couldn't be particularly bright. I believe it's normal for direct sunlight in HDR scenes to be *brighter* than that - which means it gets clamped to white in the image (avoiding that is why they use tonemapping) but the rest of the scene isn't terribly dark.

Comment: The light intensity is 10, so rgb color is  2550, 2550, 2550

Comment: For tone mapping if i remember well it as to be done only wen going from HDR to LDR. But my rendering buffers are pure HDR and can be saved to EXR format.

Answer (score 0):

Aplying gamma correction with a factor of 1.0/2.2f helps but the render still lack global illumination.

[image]